# Why ssh-keygen and ssh fingerprint is different?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

```
xiaojie@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa 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 xiaojie@ubuntu
xiaojie@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa
4096 SHA256:ovjUzYquVMajDQv8AXlbXU+X+zucgrulucC8aQqbD8g xiaojie@ubuntu (RSA)
xiaojie@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
4096 SHA256:ovjUzYquVMajDQv8AXlbXU+X+zucgrulucC8aQqbD8g xiaojie@ubuntu (RSA)
```

```
xiaojie@ubuntu:~/.ssh$ ssh xiaojie@ubuntu 
The authenticity of host 'ubuntu (127.0.1.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:f2TduTCqvnPtV0X4NjJuGWTCTvv1zrZ6o02pR7l91PE.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

why the fingerprint from `ssh localhost` and the result of `ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` is different?

Comment: No. My `id_rsa.pub` ends with `xiaojie@ubuntu` , and I use `ssh xiaojie@ubuntu` to connect . `ubuntu` is 127.0.0.1

Comment: @kyakya You are looking at two different hashes. One is for the machine useful. And the  `id_rsa.pub` is your own public key. The fact the `id_rsa.pub` ends with `xiaojie@ubuntu` is meaningless; that is considered a comment to help you know what the key the precedes it means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You're looking at two separate keys.

`ssh localhost` displays the fingerprint of the destination host's public key. That key is usually stored in the `/etc/ssh` directory of the destination host.

Host keys are used to confirm that you've connected to the intended host and prevent person-in-the-middle attacks.

`ssh-keygen -lf ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` displays the fingerprint of the (default) public key that you use for identifying/authenticating a user login. This is a key that the `ssh` command on your local host uses for logging in to a remote host. Your `localhost` will **never** present this key to someone trying to log in - instead, it expects to see things encrypted by this key.

`ssh-keygen` on a private key file will automatically give you results from the corresponding public key file. That's why you see the same result when you run it on both private and public key files.

To see the matching result of the host key from `ssh localhost` try `ssh-keygen -lf /etc/ssh/KEYFILENAME` where KEYFILENAME is something like `ssh_host_key_ecdsa.pub`. The exact name and location of that file may vary with your Linux distribution. You'll need to be root to see it.

Comment: For `Ubuntu` and `Fedora` the directory is `/etc/ssh/` - just being curious - What OS you used to indicate the `/etc/ssh_config/` directory?

Comment: You are right, I've updated the text accordingly. Thanks for your other suggested edits!